# Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined.

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

Been working on an workorder application and its been going along just fine. I downloaded and install Crystal reports the other day and designed a report in my project. After coding for a bit i decided to test it out. When I rebuilt my solution in VS 2010 I suddenly came up with 66 errors.

I have a felling the main ones are:
    Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined
    Type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.IParameterField' is not defined.
    Type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport' is not defined.

I have searched online and it seems to be a lack of references causing this.
I found a guide and located the following files:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportSoruce.dll
```

Then I right clicked on my project, went to add reference, then browse, then selected those files listed above.

All my errors went away. Then I rebuilt my project and the 66 errors came right back.
So did I add my references wrong or is there something else i need to do?
I cant even build my project anymore, it just fails. If you need some of my code let me know. Im not sure what code would be relevant to this.

Comment: Have you tried to clean & rebuild your project? I had a lot of random errors with Crystal Reports. I switched to Microsoft's report viewer (in visual studio's professional version) and found it much easier to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, i figured it out. It was a framework problem. Here is a where i found the answer...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/08287c95-5d0d-4894-8dda-e624fb088463/

this is the solution...

Right click your project, select properties, under the first "Application" tab, CHANGE your "Target framework" to .net Framework 4, because the message above is saying it is currently ".net 4 Client Profile"

That dll will ONLY work if your project is .net 4 FULL profile, NOT client profile.